# What are the utilization rates for each of the major languages and platforms?

Tags: cross-platform, programming-languages

I'm interested in knowing how many developers use each of the major languages/platforms, but I haven't been able to find any good recent surveys.  If you know of any good data, please provide a link along with a brief synopsis of the survey's methodology (who they surveyed and how etc.) and its conclusions (16% of developers use Java, 12% use RoR etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no affiliation with the [Tiobe Index](http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html): it is cited often for these kinds of questions. Its accuracy and methodology are sometimes questioned as these kinds of metrics must be very difficult.

See [this Dr Dobb's article](http://www.ddj.com/development-tools/207401593) for more...

Comment: Thanks.  I was trying to think of the Tiobe index, but I couldn't remember it.

Comment: Tiobe had some unexpected results.  Delphi climbing?  Maybe because it doesn't require .NET to do Windows apps.  And I didn't think anyone even used D.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the nearest to anything objective would be to aggregate the revenues of vendors of development platforms, to the extent that it is possible.

Comment: Who's the vendor for Ruby-on-Rails, for example?

Comment: Well, does anyone sell services/products that relate to rails as such?
The point is that all surveys have huge problems with method, but if you can track the money flows, then you can at least see which one is most cared about by peopl putting their money where their mouths are.

Answer (score 0):

jobs ads can be indicative of what the industry is after. here's some [stats](http://www.itjobswatch.co.uk/jobs/uk/c++%20developer.do) for the uk.

though not directly what you're after it might be interesting.